# What is the fastest way to read unix cgroup files from Java?

Tags: java, file, optimization

While running a resource intensive computation in Java, I'd like to read the content of cca. 10-15 files in the `cgroup` folder (like `cpuacct.usage_user`, or something from `blkio`).

I've created a `collect` Runnable object, which would be executed by a `SchedulerExecutorService` in every 5s.
How should I implement the reading algorithm to minimize the overhead of file reading?

```
public void collectData() {
        Runnable collect = () -> {
            String[] filePaths = {""}; // assume it's not empty
            String[] fileContent = new String[filePaths.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.length; i++) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePaths[i])));

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }

                    fileContent[i] = sb.toString();
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(collect, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Arrays.stream` and a `forEach` on your `filePaths` and [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) to collect the content. Also, think we need the `StringBuilder` at a higher scope to actually gather the lines. Like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Runnable collect = () -> {
    String[] filePaths = { "" }; // assume it's not empty
    String[] fileContent = new String[filePaths.length];
    Arrays.stream(filePaths).forEach(fp -> {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File(fp).toPath());
        sb.append(lines.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
    });
};
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(collect, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```